# Variable length register slices in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I need to concatenate a register, and a variable-length part of another. I have register `offset` which counts how many bits of the variable-length register I need.

I would like to do something like this:

`A <= {B[offset:0], A};`

However, this is a compilation error. 
I could write a mux that chooses different assignment for A, for different values of offset: i.e:

```
if (offset == 1) 
   A <= {B[1:0], A};
else if (offset == 2)
   A <= {B[2:0], A};
```

etc. This is cumbersome, ugly and not extensible for new values of offset. Are there any better ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mask

```
A <= { B & (2**(offset+1)-1)}
```

Note that in your example, `A<= {whatever,A}` will always be just `A`.